# Azure tools v 2.6 incompatibility with vs 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

Just updated visual studio 2015, and I have a solution that has an API using azure tools v2.6, the update for visual studio had me install v2.7 azure tools.

I cannot convert the outdated project to v2.7 as it is asking me to, and 2.6 is not compatible with vs 2015. I need to access this project and continue working on it.

Anyone have this issue? Know of any work arounds?

Exact alert message:

This project is associated with Microsoft Azure Tools - v2.6 which is not supported in Visual Studio 2015. You must upgrade the project to target Microsoft Azure Tools -v2.7.

Download Microsoft Azure Tools -v2.7(already done)
Convert the project to target Microsoft Azure Tools -v2.7 (I can't, it is in production, and i don't have rights to do so)

Comment: I'm having this same issue, albeit with slightly different versions. 2.6 project with VS 2015 installed. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - If you still have access to VS 2013, install the 2.7 SDK for 2013, upgrade the project in 2013 and then try opening in 2015 w/ 2.7.